# A distribution close to negative binomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, density-function

Assume we have k success in a sequences of N independent experiments. The probability mass function of $N$, given $k$, is proportional to
$$P(N=x) \propto \dfrac{x!}{(x-k)!} (1-p)^{x-k}$$
where $p$ is the probability of sucess. My question is this: **does this law have a name as a known standard distribution?**

With a litte modification, we could say that $N_k = N-k \sim$ Negative Binomial distribution, but that is not correct. In fact, the Negative Binomial assumes that the last experiment is a success, but in my case there is no conditionning.

Comment: "Binomial" is close enough.

Comment: Yes but in the case of binomial, the variable is k. here the variable is N

Comment: Have you checked if the sum equals to $1$?

Comment: No. May be my probability is wrong. It seems that is is greater than 1. But what is the low of the number of experiments that give k success? where k is fixed.